# ArangoDB Query Attribute Embedded in List

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql, nosql

I have a document embedded in a list, and I need to query for documents matching the value of a series of Strings.

My document:

[image]

As you can see, I have a regular document. Inside that document is "categories" which is of an unknown length per document. Inside categories I have "confidence" and "title". I need to query to find documents which have a titles matching a list of title I have in an ArrayList. The query I thought would work is:

`FOR document IN documents FILTER document.categories.title IN @categories RETURN article`

@categories is an ArrayList with a list of titles. If any of the titles in the ArrayList are in the document, I would like it to be returned.

This query seems to be returning `null`. I don't think it is getting down to the level of comparing the ArrayList to the "title" field in my document. I know I can access the "categories" list using `[#]` but I don't know how to search for the "title"s in "categories".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query

```
FOR document IN documents 
  FILTER document.categories.title IN @categories 
  RETURN article
```

would work if `document.categories` is a scalar, but it will not work if `document.categories` is an array. The reason is that the array on the left-hand side of the `IN` operator will not be auto-expanded.

To find the documents the query could be rewritten as follows:

```
FOR document IN documents 
  FILTER document.categories[*].title IN @categories 
  RETURN document
```

or

```
FOR document IN documents 
  LET titles = (
    FOR category IN document.categories
      RETURN category.title
  )
  FILTER titles IN @categories 
  RETURN document
```

Apart from that, `article` will be unknown unless there is a collection named `article`. It should probably read `document` or `document.article`.